# Execution Error, return code 30041 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I am working Zeppelin and I have connected hive interpreter. But, the hive interpreter couldn't run the following query:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payroll WHERE MASTER_DEPARTMENT_AGENCY_DESC = 'HEALTH AND SENIOR SERVIC`ES';

Error is:

Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 30041 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. Failed to create Spark client for Spark session 27023d46-9c52-4447-b4fa-e9bfe2b19e45

I checked that my docker services are working and also checked configuration its fine. Because select * was working, with where and insert as well.